# How to add div tag after wrap with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I want to change the following,

```
<div id="system">
   <div id="product_cont img">
      <img src="image1.jpg" />
      <img src="image2.jpg" />
      <img src="image3.jpg" />
..
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Nunc porta euismod luctus. Curabitur vehicula scelerisque diam at vestibulum.     
Pellentesque in lacus et augue malesuad.
   </div>
</div>
```

to like this.

```
<div id="system">
    <div id="product_cont img">
      <ul class="cont_thumb">
        <li><img src="image1.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="image2.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="image3.jpg" /></li>
         ...
       </ul>
       <div style="clear:both;"></div>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Nunc porta euismod luctus. Curabitur vehicula scelerisque diam at vestibulum.     
Pellentesque in lacus et augue malesuad
    </div>
</div>
```

When I use the following I can wrap images with `<li>` and `<ul>`.

```
$("#system #product_cont img").wrapAll("<ul class=\"cont_thumb\">").wrap("<li>");
```

But I am not sure how to add this after the `</ul>` tag with jquery:

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
$("#system #product_cont img").wrapAll("<ul class=\"cont_thumb\">").wrap("<li>").after('<div style="clear:both;"></div>');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `<li>` elements are floating, you can just put this in your CSS (*instead of* adding that `<div>`):

```
#cont_thumb { overflow: auto; }
```

So it'll factor in their height when figuring out its own.  [Quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org) has [a pretty good article on alternative approaches to clearing floats here](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html).  Also `id="product_cont img"` isn't valid, even in HTML5, you should use IDs that don't contain spaces to avoid side-effects and CSS selector pains.

*Edited for comments:* If you're zooming and need a full clear (and `overflow: none` also doesn't fit the bill), you can do this:

```
$("#system #product_cont img").wrapAll('<ul class="cont_thumb">').wrap('<li />')
                         .closest('ul').after('<div style="clear:both;"></div>');
```

Comment: It clears out. However I am zooming up images, so it create unnecessary scroll bar on the right and bottom.

Comment: @shin - Ah in that case,  `$(".cont_thumb").after('<div style="clear:both;"></div>');` after what you currently have should work. Or, tack `.closest('ul').after('<div style="clear:both;"></div>');` on the end.

Answer (score 0):

`$("#system #product_cont img").append('<div style="clear:both;'></div>")` should be sufficient.

Comment: This add div at the end of #product_cont div. I need it after ul tag. Before words, lorm etc.